# CORS Errors when calling the same Endpoint via a loop, but passing different Query Strings

Tags: c#, .net, api, cors, webassembly

We are having an issue when calling an endpoint via a loop, and most of the requests are returning the expected prelight/fetch, but some (1-2) return a CORS issue. When we look into the CORS itself, it seems like its missing the Origins/Methods/Credentials Headers that are passed. This is also only happening for a single developer, where as when I run the same scenario, all these requests return their expected 204/200 for the preflight/fetch.

[image]

We have a custom HttpClient hooked into a Blazor WASM App that has a configure handler to hook into the localhost:apiPort since theres some Azure AD Authentication going on here as well..

```
public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
    NavigationManager navigationManager)
    : base(provider, navigationManager)
{
    ConfigureHandler(
        authorizedUrls: new[] { 
            "https://localhost:44365" });

}
```

Which we then Register in the WASM

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<AuthorizedApiHttpClient>("API", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(httpClientAddress);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

This is then followed by the API being setup to Use Cors and have a default and very open Policy

```
builder.Services.AddCors()
...

app.UseCors(x => x
                 .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                 .AllowCredentials());
app.UseCorsMiddleware();
```

So from my understanding here, we have a WASM Client, from origin https://localhost:44370/ that is making request to an API at https://localhost:44365/, with explicitly open CORS policies, but even still some requests for a single client are failing?

When the developer/and myself take the same request and call it from Postman, the request returns the expected result, leaving me to believe the request itself should be fine.

This is also the code from the UseCorsMiddleware class that we are also adding

```
public class CorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}

// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Any Ideas as to why some requests have a CORS issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometimes a CORS error is covering up another error which occurs in the pipeline before the CORS policy is applied. Is it possible that's what's happening?

Comment: @SBFrancies Thats what the underlying theme seems to be across the application in general, anytime we see a CORS issue - there is likely a root cause that unfortunately the CORS issue is hiding. We did however decide to refactor the logic and do a Post with the Payload instead of a foreach which in general is the better way to go and doing this we have yet to see a CORS for the given endpoint.